# Is this linear amplifier topology regarded as Class B amplifier?

Tags: analog, linear-regulator

We learnt in the textbook that a class B amplifier takes the following configuration (NMOS on top and PMOS on the bottom, circuit 1):

[image]
Circuit 1

However, I have also seen some linear amplifiers take the following form (PMOS on top and NMOS at the bottom, circuit 2)

[image]
Circuit 2

In circuit 2, both transistors are in common source stage and I found that circuit 2 would have the following problems:

1. When Vin is high, PMOS is off and NMOS is on. As Vout and Vin has 180-degree phase shift, Vout is low. It is likely that Vout < Vin. That is the drain of the NMOS is lower than the gate of the NMOS, driving the NMOS into the triode region.
2. Similarly, when Vin is low, PMOS is on and NMOS is off. As Vout and Vin has 180-degree phase shift, Vout is high. It is likely that Vout > Vin. That is the drain of the PMOS is higher than the gate of the PMOS, driving the PMOS into the triode region.
   That means both transistors are either turned off or operate in the triode region.

So my questions are:

- Is circuit 2 regarded as Class B amplifier? If not, what topology is it?
- What is the operation is circuit 2?
- Would the potential problems described above happen? How these problems are solved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Circuit 2 is not an amplifier topology. It is called a half-bridge, not an amp. It will only operate properly digitally. It is a building block in inverters, motor drives, and class D-amps.

However, there is more to it than what you have drawn and it is not driven the way you have drawn due to technical issues. And often an NMOS is also used on the top side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean circuit 2 can be used as a switching converter?

Comment: @PhaeLeung Yes, but you would not drive both gates directly with the signal as you have drawn mainly because of shoot through. The transistors would be operated as switches.

Comment: Thanks. I understand if circuit 2 has to be used a switching converter, the gates have to be connected to the gating signals.